# Subtract tool in Weight Paint doesnt work on some specific points

Tags: weight-painting

When I try to subtract these particual vertexs it doesn't work . It happens for all other arms as well.
[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selected the face mask for weight painting. In this mode you can only tweak faces which have been previously selected in edit-mode.

Click on this icon :

[image]